# Field Calculator is not calculating selection from Make Feature Layer in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, feature-layer

I am trying to use field calculator to calculate 3 different fields in python from a Make Feature Layer variable.  It calculates the first field (MATERIAL_T) but then it doesn't calculate the second two fields (COMP_YR_N and Hierarchy_Material).

```
cal = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(servLoc, "ServiceLocation", "MATERIAL_T IS Null", outLoc)

arcpy.CalculateField_management (cal, "MATERIAL_T", "\"Unknown\"", "PYTHON")
arcpy.CalculateField_management (cal, "COMP_YR_N", 1800, "PYTHON")
arcpy.CalculateField_management (cal, "Hierarchy_Material", "\"Unknown\"", "PYTHON")
```

Comment: What is the error message when you run that code snippet exactly as-is?  It should say something like "servLoc is not defined".  Can you provide a code snippet that works up to where you are stuck, please?

Comment: It runs just fine.  Just doesn't populate the last two fields.

Comment: #Service Location
servLoc = "Standardized_ServiceLocation"
#Service Feature Class
serv = "Standardized_Service"

#Service Iterate Field
iterFld = "SERVICEID"

#Service Read Field
instYr = "COMP_YR_N"

#Service Update Field
oldYrFld = "Oldest_Job_Year"

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Also, as a new user be sure to take the [Tour]. What are `servLoc` and `outLoc` set to prior to those lines?  Without that you would not seem to be presenting a working code snippet that we can test with confidence rather than guessing the values you may have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cal = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(servLoc, "ServiceLocation", "MATERIAL_T IS Null", outLoc)
```

This is creating a new layer with a definition query `MATERIAL_T IS NULL`.  As soon as you calculate the `MATERIAL_T` field you have no records where `MATERIAL_T IS NULL` so the next two `CalculateField` are (correctly) run on an empty layer (everything filtered).

Either change the order of your `CalculateField` to Calculate `MATERIAL_T` last, or make your new feature layer without query, and then `SelectLayerByAttribute`.

Reordered:

```
cal = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(servLoc, "ServiceLocation", "MATERIAL_T IS Null", outLoc)

arcpy.CalculateField_management (cal, "COMP_YR_N", 1800, "PYTHON")
arcpy.CalculateField_management (cal, "Hierarchy_Material", "\"Unknown\"", "PYTHON")
arcpy.CalculateField_management (cal, "MATERIAL_T", "\"Unknown\"", "PYTHON")
```

or with Selection:

```
cal = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(servLoc, "ServiceLocation", "", outLoc)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("ServiceLocation", "NEW_SELECTION", "MATERIAL_T IS NULL")

arcpy.CalculateField_management (cal, "MATERIAL_T", "\"Unknown\"", "PYTHON")
arcpy.CalculateField_management (cal, "COMP_YR_N", 1800, "PYTHON")
arcpy.CalculateField_management (cal, "Hierarchy_Material", "\"Unknown\"", "PYTHON")
```

Comment: This also gives the same results.

Comment: Ok I'll dig deeper

Comment: @KyleShort I've updated this answer

Comment: Thanks for the help @Midavalo.  I ended up going with the second one.